# LoopJ AndroidAsyncHttp redirect not working

Tags: android, http, https, http-redirect, android-async-http

I have an android application where I have authentication and authorization services. Recently we had to change our URL's from http to https. I really don't want to resubmit app to the app store with urls changed to https.

Main problem I am facing is, asynchttpclient returning status code 200 without response, why I am not getting 301 which I am getting when I try to call service through advanced rest client.

I tried this already:

aesHttpClient.getHttpClient().getParams().setParameter(ClientPNames.ALLOW_CIRCULAR_REDIRECTS, false);

I want to know how can I redirect in asynchttpclient?

Please help

Answer (score 2):

```
AsyncHttpClient client = new AsyncHttpClient()；
client.setEnableRedirects(true);
```

Comment: I think it would be more helpful for the op and further visitors, when you add some explaination to your intension